# Inserting multiple values in SQL work, but from C# wont work

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to optimise the code for an insert statement in SQLite.
I have a problem when inserting multiple values into SQLite from C# Application.
If I try this directly into SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TBL4 (ID,zID,d) VALUES (6144,1,1),(6144,1,2);
```

the statement writes two rows of data into table name TBL4.

But, if I want to use this statement in c# and execute it, I have some errors getting from database (error is random.)

Here is the code from c#:

```
//this is just db connection
string connstr = "Data Source = "+frm.basedir+";"+frm.basever+";";
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connstr);
conn.Open();



//working code, successful inserted data into SQL
//g and d variable contain values: 6144 and 2
string sql3 = "INSERT INTO tbl3 (id,d) values (" + g + "," + d + ")";
SQLiteCommand comm3 = new SQLiteCommand(sql3, conn);
comm3.ExecuteNonQuery();

//not working code, throws an error
string sql4 = "INSERT INTO tbl4 (ID,zID,d) VALUES (6144,1,1),(6144,1,2)";
SQLiteCommand comm4 = new SQLiteCommand(sql4, conn);
comm4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My SQLitedatabse is 3.8 version.

Thank in advance

Comment: Do you get an exception when executing that statement ? What does it say ? You are confusing with a random error, what do you mean by that errors are never random. You did not forget to clean the db with the previous insert ? Otherwise you get a key or index violation.

Comment: this error: {"SQLite error\r\nnear \",\": syntax error"}

Comment: Well then, it is clear that you have a syntax error. It is anyway a bad idea not to use parameterized query so you should abandon this approach anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will use parameterized query.

Comment: And what version of the C# SQLite driver are you using?

Comment: Aha... the problem is in SQL driver. Thank you, I use an 'old timer' version of SQL driver, 1.0.66.

Comment: But you should still not use string coded sql queries in your program. It is asking for problems like Sql injection attacks for instance and it makes the code less readable too.